# How can I decode nested JSON in SwiftUI?

Tags: json, swift, rest

## Problem

I have created a custom search engine with Google's custom search API, and would like to display selected results in my swiftUI app.

The complete JSON can be found [here.](https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyBYICPHm9JtYCK_y5LtCxaZ23w_-EMECYU&cx=156370c9cc30c4c53&q=lyles)

I want to retrieve the "title" and "link" for each instance of "items" to display.

Sample JSON edited for clarity:

```
{
  "kind": "customsearch#search",
  "url": { ...
  },
  "queries": { ...
  },
  "context": {
    "title": "Running News"
  },
  "searchInformation": {
    "searchTime": 0.356204,
    "formattedSearchTime": "0.36",
    "totalResults": "2930",
    "formattedTotalResults": "2,930"
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "customsearch#result",
      "title": "DyeStat.com - Issam Asinga Runs 9.83w 100m, Beats Noah Lyles",
      "link": "https://www.dyestat.com/gprofile.php?mgroup_id=44531&do=news&news_id=660245",
      ...
    },
```

## Code So Far

```
import SwiftUI

struct Response: Codable { // queries
    let items: [Items]
    
    struct Items: Codable {
        let title: String
        let link: String
    }
}


struct NewsView: View {
    @State private var responseItems = [Response.Items]()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(responseItems, id: \.link) { item in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(item.link)
                }
            }
            .task {
                await loadData()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func loadData() async {
        let url: String = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?"
        let apiKey: String = "AIzaSyBYICPHm9JtYCK_y5LtCxaZ23w_-EMECYU"
        let searchEngineId: String = "156370c9cc30c4c53"
        let query: String = "Lyles"
        
        guard let url = URL(string: "\(url)key=\(apiKey))&cx=\(searchEngineId)&q=\(query)&num(5)") else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }
        
        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)

            do {
                let decodedResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
                responseItems = decodedResponse.items
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        } catch {
            print("Invalid data")
        }
    }
}
```

## Result

When I run in XCode, I'm getting the following error:

keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "items", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "items", intValue: nil) ("items").", underlyingError: nil))

"items" matches the text in the JSON, so I'm not sure why codingKeys would be necessary.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Paste the real JSON into QuickType.io . What you are actually getting not what you think you are getting. Print the data to console.

Comment: add `print("---> data: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) as AnyObject)")` just after the `let (data, _) = try await ...`, and you will see clearly what you get from the server. In my test I get the API key is not valid.

Comment: Thanks everyone so far. I will have to test this later today after work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all please name `Items` in singular form `Item`, **one** instance represents **one** item.

---

This is a good example why it is strongly discouraged to compose URLs with String Interpolation.

**The error occurs because there are two closing parentheses after `apiKey`, the second one is wrong because it is treated as part of the API key.**

A more reliable (and recommended) way is `URLComponents` and `URLQueryItem` especially with many query key/value pairs.

This version of `loadData` throws all errors which can be handled on the caller side

```
func loadData() async throws {
    let baseURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?"
    let apiKey = "AIzaSyBYICPHm9JtYCK_y5LtCxaZ23w_-EMECYU"
    let searchEngineId = "156370c9cc30c4c53"
    let query = "Lyles"
    
    var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: baseURL)!
    urlComponents.queryItems = [
        URLQueryItem(name: "key", value: apiKey),
        URLQueryItem(name: "cx", value: searchEngineId),
        URLQueryItem(name: "q", value: query),
        URLQueryItem(name: "num", value: "5")
    ]
    
    guard let url = urlComponents.url else { throw URLError(.badURL) }
    let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
    let decodedResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
    responseItems = decodedResponse.items
}
```

And catch the errors – better show an appropriate error message to the user – in `.task`

```
.task {
    do {
        try await loadData() 
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thank you Vadian! Were you able to run and retrieve the data after removing the extra closing bracket? I'm away from my machine until tonight and can't run it. Thanks so much!

Comment: Yes, your code works after removing one parenthesis, but I highly recommend my suggestion.

Comment: Hi Vadian, your solution regarding the extra parentheses and URLComponents DID solve one issue. Thank you! I am still having trouble showing the data in my view. Do you have any ideas on how to do this? Thank you.

I added `print("---> data: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) as AnyObject)")` after `let (data, _) = try await ...` and can clearly see the entire JSON is present.

Comment: This is another question, but the code seems to be correct. Is it guaranteed that all `link`s are unique? Better add some unique `id`entifier.

Comment: Ah, thanks for your suggestion Vadian. I added a UUID to `Item` but it caused a new bug. The real issue I noticed, is `.task { }` on the `List`, instead of `NavigationView`. As soon as I moved `.task{ }` to the `NavigationView`, it worked!

Thanks again for your help Vadian.